# mongodb wiredtiger engine from ext4 to xfs

Tags: mongodb

I am having performance issue related to mongodb wiredtiger engine on an ext4 filesystem (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems)

I have a replicaset with 2 servers and one arbitrer (all on ext4).

I would like to know if there is any issue to add a new server into this replicaset with a different filesystem (in my case XFS), the idea is to add new XFS secondaries and promote one to primary before shutting done the old ones that are on ext4.

Comment: Replica set members can definitely use different filesystems -- members aren't even aware of what filesystems are in use by their peers. Aside from startup warnings, what issues are you seeing with ext4 and MongoDB? You may want to post your performance issue as a question on DBA StackExchange with more details (specific versions of MongoDB, O/S, and any error messages or unexpected behaviour).

Comment: Thanks. My issue is related to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18314 with a periodic freeze every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replica set members can definitely use different filesystems -- members aren't even aware of what filesystems are in use by their peers.

Although use of the Ext4 filesystem is one possibility for performance issues with MongoDB and WiredTiger (particularly under significant write load), there may be other issues affecting your use case. Details like the specific version of MongoDB server, O/S version, startup warnings, and any log messages correlating with the period of slowdown might provide more insight if you decide to post a follow-up question to investigate your periodic performance problem. Other deployment details like hosting (bare metal vs cloud), server resources (RAM, CPU, disk type), and `mongod` configuration changes could also be relevant.

Since you suspect a performance issue related to the use of Ext4, I would try to isolate changes to your MongoDB deployment to try to confirm this theory (especially if your periodic stalls are consistently reproducible):

- If you only see periodic stalls on one member of the replica set (eg. the primary), try stepping down the current primary so the members swap roles. Slow/under-provisioned I/O (or noisy neighbour in a cloud/shared hosting environment) can sometimes be the culprit. You may also find that there is some other factor based on the role of the member (for example, if your application is reading from secondaries).
- If you see periodic stalls on both current data-bearing members, add a new member using XFS for the `storage.dbPath` to test if this new member exhibits the same behaviour.
- If you aren't already running the latest minor release for your version of MongoDB, upgrade. For example, if you are running MongoDB 3.4.2 and the latest version of 3.4.x available is 3.4.10 it would definitely be worth testing the newest stable release. Upgrades within the same production release series include bug fixes and stability improvements but should not introduce any compatibility changes.

Other suggestions:

- Review the MongoDB logs for any suspect activity or log messages that might correlate with periods of slowdown or stalls. For example, the [TTL (Time-To-Live)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) index expiry task runs every 60 seconds and could be deleting a significant number of documents. There may be slow queries or other relevant warnings logged.
- Assuming you have some metric monitoring in place, review the metrics of your MongoDB deployment to look for outliers or patterns coinciding with your periods of poor performance.
- If you are running more than a few major releases behind the latest production release series of MongoDB, consider testing a major version upgrade in a representative staging/development environment. There have been significant improvements in successive major releases.
- For general information on tuning deployments it is also worthwhile to review the [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/).